# Error in downloading Packages e.g. VLC media player

Tags: installation, software-center, package-management

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04, but when i tried to install VLC media player from Ubuntu software center some cache update occured(as far as i could remember) but i could not install it because it took so much time getting download and installed. Then I shut down my PC.

When I again tried to install VLC I got this error..

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
 Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
 Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

How to fix it up??

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal, type `sudo apt-get install -f`. This attempts to fix broken dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the terminal.

Run @Alaa Ali's code `sudo apt-get install -f` and then `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`. 
If that doesn't work then try running `sudo apt-get purge vlc && sudo apt-get update` Once one of these fixes works, try installing vlc via the terminal `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: These codes are not helping me.Still getting the same error.